# Construir panel de administración de host remotos

Tags: web, servidor

Me causa curiosidad como se construyen esos paneles tipo panel de emergencia de digitalocean , en la que accedes a tu servidor cloud , o de este tipo(son servidores de laboratorio de cisco)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

accedi por la web , sin instalar nada , sin configurar nada , sé que stackoverflow es muy estricto con respecto a las preguntas divagantes,mi pregunta es simple , información para construir este tipo de sistemas?.

Comment: Dudo entre cerrarla por `basada en opiniones` o `demasiado amplia` o `no está claro lo que se pregunta`. Mientras me lo pienso, publico una respuesta ;-) Para que puedas ir buscando en Google.

Answer (score 3):

No tiene ningún misterio. No es mas que una *interfaz web*, que muestra información.

El *truco* está en saber **de donde recogen** dicha información. Hay **muchas** posibilidades:

- Hay programas especializados, como [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), que instalan *agentes* en los equipos a monitorizar.
- Sistemas genéricos de publicación y edición de dicha información (protocolo [SNMP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol)).
- Sistemas privados, que utilizan bases de datos de clientes, con tablas para la información relevante de dicho cliente (equipos activos, IP de los mismo, ... ).
- Combinación de las anteriores: usar una base de datos para buscar los equipos del cliente, SNMP para información básica, y *agentes* para información adicional/extendida.

En fin, que depende **exactamente** de lo que quieras hacer y de **como** quieras hacerlo.

Comment: es la información que necesitaba,sin embargo no es que solo muestren , uno puede interactuar con el equipo remoto , puedo abrir chrome , abrir mi facebook desde ese host ,etc

Comment: Puedes buscar sobre `html5 rdp` (Remote Desktop Protocol). Creo que hay mas protocolos, pero no los recuerdo :-/